# How to adequately add identical public-private ssh key to a new client machine?

Tags: ssh, public-key, ssh-keygen

I have generated private and public key pair files (id_rsa, id_rsa.pub) using *ssh-keygen* command in a machine A, which is a client. I have tested my connection to server in machine A and it is working fine.
Now I have copy those files using **cp** command to a machine B (~/.ssh folder) and I can't login anymore. Once I deleted my public key file, I can successfully login into server. However, my X2goclient can't connect and prompt up multiple times the paraphrase window with and without the public key.

What is the adequate procedure to copy those keys from client to client (Machine A to Machine B)?

Thanks!

Comment: ensure that file permissions are correct. (cp -a)

Comment: the permissions for id_rsa are 600 and for id_rsa.pub are 644

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, I don't think your problem lies with key generation but with installation of your key on Machine B.
Instead of using cp use following command for copying

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/home/rsapath user@host
```

First you have to enter server login password (not your RSA password). Once the keys are added, login into your sever using

```
ssh 'user@host'
```

Enter RSA password here.
Hope this solution helps.